# How to search specific content (with or without regular expression) in pdf?

Tags: java, itext

I have a list of PDF files. I want to search for the presence of specific content in each of these files and separate a file that has the content from the other files. I want a know whether such a search function is possible using the Java library iText.

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes, it's probably possible, but it depends on the nature of your PDFs." You should be more specific, because it's not possible (1) if your files consist of scanned images or (2) if the fonts don't allow text extraction. If your next question will be "How can I do this", then you should first show what you have tried. For instance: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693706/english-text-extracted-using-itextpdf-is-not-understandable)?

Comment: *specific content* - please also specify the nature of that specific content. Is it just a sequence of words on a line? Is it an image? Is it a background coloration?